# How to write a base32_decode in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unpack, phpjs

I'm trying to create the equivalent of PHP's unpack. I've noticed the project PHPJS doesn't have it. I need it for the implementation of base32_encode and base32_decode (using [Crockford's alphabet](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html) '0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ').

I couldn't find it anywhere and judging from it's counterpart, [PHPJS's pack function](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/raw/master/functions/misc/pack.js) I doubt my version will be complete and bug free any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

```
base32tohex = (function() {
    var dec2hex = function(s) {
        return (s < 15.5 ? "0" : "") + Math.round(s).toString(16)
    }
      , hex2dec = function(s) {
        return parseInt(s, 16)
    }
      , base32tohex = function(base32) {
        for (var base32chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567", bits = "", hex = "", i = 0; i < base32.length; i++) {
            var val = base32chars.indexOf(base32.charAt(i).toUpperCase());
            bits += leftpad(val.toString(2), 5, "0")
        }
        for (i = 0; i + 4 <= bits.length; i += 4) {
            var chunk = bits.substr(i, 4);
            hex += parseInt(chunk, 2).toString(16)
        }
        return hex
    }
      , leftpad = function(str, len, pad) {
        return len + 1 >= str.length && (str = new Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(pad) + str),
        str
    };
    return base32tohex;
}
)()
```

Comment: To conform to [rfc4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-6), the for loop calculating the hex representation should instead be `for (i = 0; i + 8 <= bits.length; i += 8)`. This is because it's illegal for base32 input to be a fractional number of bytes, so we must ignore any bits left over at the end of the decoded string.